# See all the Java versions installed on Mac

Tags: java

How can I get all the Java versions installed on my Mac?

Is there a terminal command for this?

When I run **`java -version`**, I get the current JRE version that is in use in my system, but I want to list all the JREs installed on my Mac.

Answer (score 442, accepted):

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

lists one line per Java environment installed (and known to the `/usr/bin/java` command).

You can still have other Java distributions which are not registered.  They are typically downloaded  as ZIP files without an installer, or using another package manager like homebrew.

Comment: Notice in case you are on MacOs and installed maven using brew, you might have another JAVA installation under /usr/local/Cellar/openjdk

Comment: Please note that the command above does not show installed Java version installed via sdkman.io

Comment: @basZero That should most likely be reported to sdkman.io as a bug then.

Comment: There seem to be only certain recognized locations where the jdk can be, such as /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines, or this java_home command won't find them.

Comment: @KevinBourrillion to my understanding the installer must actively register the JVM for this to work.

Answer (score 29):

**The accepted solution didn't work for me**.

The results it returned didn't include all the Java versions installed.
For example on my machine there are currently 5 installations, but the accepted solution only returns 3.

**What eventually did work for me is**:

```
mdfind -name 'java' | grep '/bin/java$'
```

It finds all java installations on the system regardless of how they were installed. This way I found the specific java installation which I was looking for.

**Explanation of how it works**:

[mdfind](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/mdfind/) is a native tool in MacOS to search for different files by given query, it's very fast (usually way faster than `find`)

The given command is looking for everything called `java` and then filter only the results that end with `/bin/java` which is the typical suffix of java installations

Comment: Ah you found the database Spotlight uses.

Comment: Out of curiosity - what were the five JVM's and which didn't register?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Hard to say what was there 6 months ago. But, I tried now again because of your question, and in current results I see this one: `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/17.0.2/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` is found with `mdfind -name 'java' | grep '/bin/java$'`, but not with `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`

Comment: Ah so installed with home brew.