# How to see all versions of Java installed on macOS?

Tags: java, macos, installation, java-8, macos-catalina

As far as I know Java's latest version is Java 14 and Java 8 is still supported. On macOS, the Java control panel in the system preferences bottom most pane leads to a window "Java Control Panel" and there the version information is Java Version 8, however when I type in the terminal java --version I get Java 14.0.1 and even /usr/libexec/java_home -V does not show my Java 8 version. How can I see All the Java versions on my Mac? Thank you.

```
❯ java --version
java 14.0.1 2020-04-14
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)
❯ /usr/libexec/java_home -V
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    14.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 14.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    13.0.1, x86_64: "Java SE 13.0.1"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    11.0.5, x86_64: "AdoptOpenJDK 11"   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

[The terminal window and the Java Control Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQlYU.png)

Comment: Commenting because I'm not on my MacBook so I can't confirm for sure, but I believe the JCP is showing you information about JRE and not JDK. To see your JDK version, try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766028/see-all-the-java-versions-installed-on-mac

Comment: Does this answer your question? [See all the java versions installed on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766028/see-all-the-java-versions-installed-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installation-jdk-and-jre-macos.htm#JSJIG-GUID-2FE451B0-9572-4E38-A1A5-568B77B146DE)

> Only one JRE can be installed on the system at any time. Installing a
> JRE removes the previously installed JRE.
>
> The JRE version installed on the system can be determined in one of
> two ways:
>
> From System Preferences, and then the Other section, click the Java
> icon. This starts the Java Control Panel. You then click About to
> display the version information.

The reason you see Java 8 in the Java Control Panel is because the control panel indicates your JRE version -- the control panel does not provide any information on installed versions of JDK, of which you may have as many as you wish.

```
java_home -V
```

will not include Java 8 because it's listing JDK versions, and your Java 8 refers only to the single installation of JRE allowed on your system.

Comment: How can I view JRE version from terminal on macOS? Also how do I uninstall it? I only want my JDK's JRE when doing java --version "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)" installed and not Java JRE 8 @MarsAtomic

Comment: @JohnSung Please note that Stack Overflow is a question and answer format site. You ask a question. It gets answered. You click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it. If you have further questions, you don't post them in a comment at the bottom of the old question -- you post a new question separately, because it is indeed a new question that may be related to, but is distinct from the old question. Please don't mistake Stack Overflow for a discussion site where you can have open ended conversations. This site uses a Q&A format to make finding answers easier down the road.