# bundling jdk 8 with Mac OS X installer

Tags: java-8, pkgbuild, productbuild

I have created a .pkg installer for mac using pkgbuild and product build. Is there a way to bundle java jdk 8 along with the package. Say newer version of java is already installed on Mac and my application is compatible with jdk 8 only.
Is there a way that bundled jdk can be put locally for that application ONLY without affecting the newer version of jdk already installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unzip OpenJDK 8 into a non-system folder (or folder of your application) and use it without affecting other already installed JDKs. There is no need for an installation or modification of global environment variables. Therefore, technically it is not a problem.

Note: Oracle's (not open) JDK has different rules regarding installation and distribution.

If starting your application produces an error:

> Error: could not find libjava.dylib Failed to GetJREPath()

This means it uses a JDK native library directly. (See [bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213362](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213362) for more  information.) In order to solve this either:

- provide the JRE path like `-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home` as described in [eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1102885](https://eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1102885)

or:

- set `$JAVA_HOME` in a script for your app.

Comment: Thanks , I was able to fix the error by modifying path in info.plist
Now I get this error 
Error: could not find libjava.dylib
Failed to GetJREPath()

Is there a way to fix it without softlinking?

Comment: This might be an issue with your application or launcher using a native library directly. Something similar is discussed in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8213362.

Comment: For Eclipse you can avoid softlinking by providing the JRE path like `-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home` as described in https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1102885/ or you could try setting $JAVA_HOME in a script for your app.

Comment: I would appreciate marking the question as solved if the answer is complete from your point of view. It is great to see Java on Mac OS although it will never become a first-class citizen as Steve Jobs once promised. See [https://jdeploy.substack.com/p/the-decline-and-fall-of-java-on-the](https://jdeploy.substack.com/p/the-decline-and-fall-of-java-on-the)

Comment: I still have a one final query regarding **info.plist**. Is there a way to embed regex in JRE path. Say a user has a different patch version of java user installed. So hard coding the path would cause run time problems. For example a regex to take any java jdk 8 path not worrying about the patch versions.

Comment: You can use environment variables in a plist and you can run a script to set them. 
 You can use `/usr/libexec/java_home -V`to find installed Java versions. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766028/see-all-the-java-versions-installed-on-mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766028/see-all-the-java-versions-installed-on-mac). Be aware that java might have been installed via `brew`, too.